# Comparator not letting me compare T values

Tags: java, generics, tree, compare, comparator

Intellij idea is giving me this error in class internalNode when trying to compare two T values: compare(capture,capture) cannot be applied to (T,T). I can't understand why. I've already changed the parametrized type to T and it still shows me the message but instead of capture just T.
Any help is very appreciated

```
public class BSpecialTree<T> {
private Node<T> root;
private int keysNumber;
private Comparator<? super T> cmp;

public BSpecialTree(Comparator<? super T> cmp, int keysNumber) {
    this.cmp = cmp;
    this.keysNumber = keysNumber;
}

public boolean belongs(T key) {
    if(key == null) {
        if(root == null)
            return true;
        return false;
    }
    return root.belongs(key);
}

private interface Node<T> {
    boolean belongs(T key);
}

private class internalNode<T> implements Node<T> { 
    private T key;
    private Node<T> left, right;

    public internalNode(T key) {
        this.key = key;
    }

    public boolean belongs(T key) {
        if(cmp.compare(this.key, key) > 0) //ERROR
            return left.belongs(key);
        return right.belongs(key);
    }
}
private class leafNode<T> implements Node<T> {
    private List<T> keys;

    public leafNode() {
        keys = new ArrayList<T>(keysNumber);
    }
    public boolean belongs(T key) {
        return keys.indexOf(key) != -1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your inner classes are introducing their own generic type `<T>` which hides `<T>` from `BSpecialTree<T>`, but comparator is declared to be using `T` from `BSpecialTree`, not from `internalNode`.

Maybe try with

```
private class internalNode implements Node<T> {
//                        ^remove `<T>` from here
```